# Переход между формами c++

Tags: c++-cli

Есть 2 формы (MyForm и MyForm 1) , нужно что бы после нажатия на кнопку (перейти) открывалась вторая форма.

```
if (Login == RL && Password == RP)
    {

        MyForm1->Show();
        MessageBox::Show("Login and Password is right!", "Your AUTH");


    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Login or Password is WRONG!", "Your AUTH");
    }


}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я добавляю в код `MyForm1->Show();` , то мне выдается ошибка (требуется идентификатор)
Начал недавно изучать плюсы, ответа не нашел пока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу путем добавления в MyForm.cpp строки `#include "MyForm1.h"` и заменив `MyForm1->Show();` на :

```
MyForm1^ frm = gcnew MyForm1;
frm->Show(this);
```